# C# Mongo driver - how to do case agnostic search

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a requirement to get all wells created by a list of users. The following is the code I wrote for this requirement. However **x.CreatedBy.ToLower()** throws an exception listed below:

````
            FilterDefinition<WellInfoDocument> userFilter = builder.Where(x => users.Contains(x.CreatedBy.ToLower()));
            var documentList = await GetCollection<WellInfoDocument>().FindAsync<WellInfoDocument>(userFilter);```


 System.ArgumentException: Unsupported filter: Contains(value(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String])).
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.Translate(Expression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.Translate(Expression node, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.CreateFindOperation[TProjection](FilterDefinition`1 filter, FindOptions`2 options)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.FindAsync[TProjection](IClientSessionHandle session, FilterDefinition`1 filter, FindOptions`2 options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.<>c__DisplayClass43_0`1.<FindAsync>b__0(IClientSessionHandle session)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.UsingImplicitSessionAsync[TResult](Func`2 funcAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)


Any suggestions to fix is welcome. TIA
````

Answer (score 0):

Give the [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) filter a go.

```
 var filter = Builders<WellInfoDocument>.Filter.In(x => x.CreatedBy.ToLower(),users.Select(x => x.Id).ToList());
 var documentList = await GetCollection<WellInfoDocument>().FindAsync<WellInfoDocument>(filter);
```

Im unsure of your types or how they look but you should be able to infer from this example.